# Идея решения задачи олимпиадного программирования

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

Есть n дробей вида ai/bi (1 <= n <= 5000, 1 <= ai, bi <= 1000000, ai, bi - натуральные). Требуется выбрать из них 1<=k<=n дробей таким образом, чтобы дробь, числитель которой равен сумме числителей этих дробей, а знаменатель равен сумме знаменателей дробей, была максимальной. В качестве ответа вывести вещественное значение этой дроби с абсолютной или относительной погрешностью не более 10^-9. Ограничение по времени 2 секунды, по памяти 256 МБайт.

Например, n=2, k=2, a0=1, b0=5, a1=2, b1=3. Здесь берутся все дроби, а результат равен (1+2)/(5+3)=3/8.

Возможный подход - динамическое программирование - пытался рассуждать в сторону вычисления dp[nUsed][nViewed] - максимального значения дроби, где nUsed - число дробей, входящих в нее, а nViewed - число просмотренных дробей. Тогда ответ будет в dp[k][n]. Но я не знаю, как этот подход улучшить, он не пройдет ни по памяти (чтобы просто хранить 25 млн значений dp, требуется 25*10^6 * 2 * sizeof(int64), ибо максимальное значение числителя и знаменателя итоговой дроби может превышать uint32), ни по времени (тут зависит от числа переходов между элементами - может, можно делать восходящую динамику и делать лишь пару переходов - из значения dp[nUsed][nViewed] обновлять значение dp[nUsed+1][nViewed+1] или dp[nUsed][nViewed+1]).

Еще пытался думать в сторону жадности. Каким-то образом отсортировать (например, по значению дробей), затем набрать k первых дробей. После этого просмотреть оставшиеся n-k дробей и смотреть, можно ли заменить какую-то из добавленных ранее дробей новой дробью, что результат улучшится.

Comment: Математически если выбрать первые (большие->маленькие), отсортированные по значению получите макс результат. Никакого перебора не надо.

Comment: Никакого улучшения не надо. Не практично. `a/b < c/d == a*d < c * b`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Рассмотрите вариант: `2/3;  1/2; 100/200; k = 2` Если сортировать по возрастанию, то можно выбрать как `(2 + 100) / (3 + 200)` так и `(2 + 1) / (3 + 2)`. Ответы получаются разные.

Comment: Или еще вариант: `1/2; 1000/4000; 1/5; k =2`. Выбирая максимальный, получим:
`1001 / 4002 =  0.25`. Правильный ответ: `(1 + 1) / (2 + 5) = 2 / 7 = 0.286`.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: codeforces.com/gym/101641/problem/E

Comment: В задаче требуется приближенное решение. Интересно, можно ли решить точно - получить ответ в виде дроби (не десятичной)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается с помощью бинарного поиска по ответу.

На каждой итерации бинарного поиска проверяем, существует ли набор из `k` дробей `ai/bi`, что `(a1+a2+...+ak)/(b1+b2+...+bk) >= x`. Если существует, то ответ как минимум `x`, иначе ответ строго меньше `x`.

Далее можно рассмотреть неравенство:

```
(a1+a2+...+ak)/(b1+b2+...+bk) >= x.
```

Поскольку `(b1+b2+...+bk) > 0`, то умножение обеих частей неравенства на эту скобку не приведет к смене знака неравенства:

```
(a1+a2+...+ak) >= x*(b1+b2+...+bk).
```

Далее раскроем скобки, перенесем все слагаемые влево и сгруппируем подобным образом:

```
(a1-x*b1)+(a2-x*b2)+...+(ak-x*bk) >= 0.
```

Далее отсортируем все пары значений `(ai, bi)` по убыванию ключа `ai-x*bi` и найдем сумму первых `k` значений `ai-x*bi`. Если эта сумма меньше `0`, то нельзя выбрать `k` пар `(ai, bi)` для выполнения неравенства, иначе можно.

На каждой итерации алгоритма поддерживается полуинтервал бинарного поиска `[left; right)`. Бинарный поиск завершается, когда достигается требуемая точность `eps`, то есть выполняется условие `left + eps >= right`. В качестве начального значения для `left` можно выбрать `0`, потому что любой набор из `k` дробей даст значение, строго большее `0`, из условия натуральности `ai` и `bi`. В качестве начального значения для `right` можно взять, например, `10^6+1` - чуть больше, чем максимальное достижимое значение `10^6 = (k * 10^6) / (k * 1)`.

Comment: По результату можно восстановить набор дробей. Пусть результат ans, тогда снова возьмем пары (ai, bi) и отсортируем по убыванию ключа ai-ans*bi. Первые k дробей будут ответом.